# The for loop to excel

Tags: java, arrays, excel

I want to create loops on the side entirely data.put . How can I do that?

> How do I create loops ?

```
    data.put("01",new Object[] { a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4], ... a[240],a[241],a[242],a[243] });
    data.put("02",new Object[] { a[244],a[245],a[246],a[247],a[248], ... a[484],a[485],a[486],a[487] });
    data.put("03",new Object[] { a[488],a[489],a[490],a[491],a[492], ... a[728],a[729],a[730],a[731] });
```

Row = 244
Column = 3

```
public void ExcelSave() throws IOException {

    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Employee Data");
    Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();

    String[] a = DataFrom.split("-");

        data.put("01",new Object[] { a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4], ... a[240],a[241],a[242],a[243] });
        data.put("02",new Object[] { a[244],a[245],a[246],a[247],a[248], ... a[484],a[485],a[486],a[487] });
        data.put("03",new Object[] { a[488],a[489],a[490],a[491],a[492], ... a[728],a[729],a[730],a[731] });
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();

int rownum = 0;
    for (String key : keyset) {

        Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);

        Object[] objArr = data.get(key);

        int cellnum = 0;

        for (Object obj : objArr) {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
            if (obj instanceof String) {
                cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
            } else if (obj instanceof Integer) {
                cell.setCellValue((Integer) obj);
            }
        }
    }
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    try {

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("ExcelSaves.xlsx"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("--> Excel Save...");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean _how to I create loops_? You may take a [tour] and have a look on [ask] first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a nested loop that does something like this:

```
final int SIZE = 244;
for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
    Object[] arr = new Object[SIZE];
    int currentColIndex = column * SIZE;
    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; i++)
        arr[row] = a[currentColIndex + row];
    data.put("0" + (column+1), arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Arrays.copyOfRange](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-T:A-int-int-) will be of help here.

```
int column = 244;
int row = 3;
Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();
for(int i = 0; i++; i < column) {
    String key = String.format("%02d",i);
    int from = i * column;
    int to = from + column;
    data.put(key , Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, from, to));
}
```